# How do you add variable values to attributes with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm attempting to create dynamically-addable cards via ReactJS. For this, I need to make new ids for div tags (for example, line 8 of my code has an input `id="question{qnum+1}_option1"`, which uses a variable. How do I use a variable in JS, along with some extra text, to give an attribute a value?

Wherever I need the div tag to have the card number (represented as variable qnum added to 1), it refuses to work.

```
<div className="col s4">
    <div className="card light-red">
        <div className="card-content blue-text">
            <span className="card-title"><div className="row"><div className="input-field col s12"><input id="question{qnum+1}_question" type="text" className="validate" /><label htmlFor="Question {qnum+1}">Question {(qnum + 1).toString()}</label></div></div></span>
            <p>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="input-field col s6"><input id="question{qnum+1}_option1" type="text" className="validate" /><label htmlFor="question{qnum+1}_option1">Option 1</label></div>
                    <div className="input-field col s6"><input id="question{qnum+1}_option2" type="text" className="validate" /><label htmlFor="question{qnum+1}_option2">Option 2</label></div>
                    <div className="input-field col s6"><input id="question{qnum+1}_option3" type="text" className="validate" /><label htmlFor="question{qnum+1}_option3">Option 3</label></div>
                    <div className="input-field col s6"><input id="question{qnum+1}_option4" type="text" className="validate" /><label htmlFor="question{qnum+1}_option4">Option 4</label></div>
                </div>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<div>` tag that wraps the whole HTML is in a `const questionFormat();`, and `questionFormat` is rendered with React.

I'm also using MaterializeCSS, but I'm pretty sure that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Basic Rule](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx):

> We can embed any JavaScript expression in JSX by wrapping it in curly
>   braces.

Instead of putting the variable inside `""`, Use **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**, like this:

```
id = {`question${qnum+1}_option1`}
```

You can also use `+` (string concatenation), like this:

```
id = {"question" + (qnum+1) + "_option1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
id={'question' + qnum+1 + '_option1'}
```